# Ubuntu is very slow at booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

I have **dual booted** windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. **Windows** take **4 seconds** to boot but **Ubuntu takes more than 45 seconds.**
Can you please fix this issue?

**My hardware specifications:**
i7 8th gen processor,
DDR4 8GB RAM,
Nvidia geforce MX110 2GB Graphics card,
1TB HDD

Output of **`systemd-analyze blame`**

```
11.514s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
11.417s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
10.929s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
 9.483s dev-sda2.device                                      
 8.405s user@125.service                                     
 8.173s udisks2.service                                      
 7.616s apport-autoreport.service                            
 7.380s accounts-daemon.service                              
 6.326s NetworkManager.service                               
 5.924s polkit.service                                       
 4.866s avahi-daemon.service                                 
 4.865s bluetooth.service                                    
 4.410s switcheroo-control.service                           
 4.398s thermald.service                                     
 4.392s systemd-logind.service                               
 4.392s wpa_supplicant.service                               
 3.788s smartmontools.service                                
 3.593s teamviewerd.service                                  
 3.564s gpu-manager.service                                  
 3.281s preload.service                                      
 3.245s ModemManager.service                                 
 3.216s apport.service                                       
 3.178s grub-common.service
```

Comment: There is a lack of actionable information here. Can you update your question to include the full output of `systemd-analyze blame`? This will contain specific details to say what processes might be taking longer during the boot sequence.

Comment: The output is long so I can't comment here but I can see lines with 25 sec or near about it.and this is the highest {45.112s plymouth-quit-wait.service}@Matigo

Comment: If you've fastboot enabled on windows 10; then you're comparing apples & baseballs..  Fastboot on windows is a form of hibernation and not a cold boot (the fastboot is created after applying updates).  For comparison you should be comparing a real cold boot of windows 10 with the cold boot of Ubuntu.

Comment: added the output of systemd-analyze blame